# Consecutive update figure matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting pairs of images from two different folders, for each pair I plotted them one after the other using: `plt.imshow()` and save the fig after each loop.

In order to speed it up I want to use the option `.set_data` so that I only update the figure and not redraw everything. Since I have to do it two times it seems to use only the last one and no update is done on the first call. I am doing somthing like this:

```
 data=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)*10
 im1=plt.imshow([data]*4) # simulating an rgb image that i read from file
 mask=np.ma.array(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)*10, mask=np.eye(3)) # 1D map
 im2=plt.imshow(mask, vmin=2, vmax=7)
 for i in range(10):
     data=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)*10 + np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3,3))
     im1.set_data([data]*4) # simulating another rgb image read from file
     mask=np.ma.array(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)*10+np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3,3)), mask=np.eye(3)) # 1D map 
     im2.set_data(mask)
     plt.savefig("{}.png".format(i))
```

with this code, only the mask is being updated but not the background image. Is there a way to make matplotlib use both updates of the data?

Comment: You should not use the same name for the different images.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the same happends if I use different names.

Comment: If that is really the case you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue, i.e. a code one can run to reproduce the error.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have edited the question and the code also.

Comment: How do you determine that the background image would not be updated? When I run the code both images are updated. This may become more apparent when setting `vmax=100`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see that but if you add this to the end: `print(mask)` `print(data)` `plt.show()` and go over the image you will see that the values correspond only to one of the images and not to both, which means only one is being updated.

Comment: I don't think that conclusion is correct. It would only mean that the values shown are incorrect. If that is what you want to ask about, maybe update the question to ask for that.